# Transform JSON objects to an new array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

How to transform JSON structure to an new array using Swift?

Initial JSON

```
{
  "group1": {
    "1/30/21": 100,
    "1/31/21": 200
  },
  "group2": {
    "1/30/21": 200,
    "1/31/21": 300
  },
  "group3": {
    "1/30/21": 300,
    "1/31/21": 500
  }
}
```

The array I'd like to convert would be like:

```
[
  {
    "group1": 100,
    "group2": 200,
    "group3": 300,
    "date": "1/30/21",
  },
  {
    "group1": 200,
    "group2": 300,
    "group3": 500,
    "date": "1/31/21",
  }
]
```

Comment: And how dynamic is the data, could there be more groups or more dates per group? Have you tried anything yourself you can share?

Comment: Yes, it could be more groups and more dates per group but each size of object is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `JSONSerialization` to convert the json to a dictionary

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonIn.data(using: .utf8)!) as! [String: [String: Int]]
```

Then in two steps convert to the expected format by first creating a dictionary where the date is the key and groups and numbers (as a tuples) are the values

```
var temp = [String: [(String, Int)]]()

dictionary.forEach { key, value in
    for (innerKey, innerValue) in value {
        temp[innerKey, default: []].append((key, innerValue))
    }
}
```

Then use this dictionary to create the array of dictionaries

```
let output = temp.map { (key, tuples) -> [String: Any] in
    var result = [String: Any]()
    for tuple in tuples {
        result[tuple.0] = tuple.1
    }
    result["date"] = key
    return result
}
```

and then back to json

```
let jsonOut = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: output)
```